# How to get images to stick to a specific elements HTML

Tags: html, css

Currently building an E-Commerce website, and I have achieved reasonably responsive images. However, I've noticed that the images seem to be where they should be when my browser window is at 100 percent. The semi-responsive images resizes according to browser as well. However when my browser resizes, the image float away from the navigation bar. Is there a method where **I can get the images to stay fixed to the navigation bar? Here is my code so they don't move away?**:

**HTML for images:**

```
<img class = "leftBanner" src = "hairtest1.jpg" alt ="Woman hair banner one">
<img class = "rightBanner" src = "hairtest2.jpg" alt ="Woman hair banner two">
```

**CSS for images:**

```
  img.leftBanner {
max-width: 50%;
max-height:auto;
position:relative;
margin-top:-6%;
margin-left:-1%;
}
img.rightBanner {
max-width:50%;
max-height:auto;
position:relative;
margin-top:-28.7%;
margin-left:60%;
}
```

**HTML for Navigation Bar:**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>L'Homme</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Femme</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Extensions</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Accessories</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Contactez</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style the images using `margin-top` and `margin-left` instead of `top` and `left`. Using `top` and `left` on absolutely positioned elements positions them relative to the browser and not the parent element.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but does not resolve the issue at hand.